# How can I tell whether a binary is compiled with frame pointers or not on Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly

I have a binary/library in Linux. How can I determine whet it was compiled with frame pointers?

Comment: You look at the disassembled object file to see if it uses the frame pointer. Unfortunately I don't remember what that looks like so this isn't a real answer.

Comment: To clarify on disassembling: `objdump -d <libYourLibrary.so>` will do the trick, just in case you're looking for a disassembler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Zan/blackwing:

Compiling some simple things with / without framepointer optimization and using `diff -u` on the disassembled output gives some clues:

```
$ diff -u with*
--- with-fp 2011-03-23 09:49:29.366277002 +0000
+++ without-fp  2011-03-23 09:49:35.046277002 +0000
@@ -5,14 +5,12 @@
 Disassembly of section .text:

 00000000 <func>:
-   0:  55                      push   %ebp
+   0:  53                      push   %ebx
    1:  31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
-   3:  89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
-   5:  53                      push   %ebx
-   6:  81 ec 00 04 00 00       sub    $0x400,%esp
-   c:  8b 4d 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%ecx
-   f:  8d 9d fc fb ff ff       lea    -0x404(%ebp),%ebx
-  15:  8d 76 00                lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
+   3:  81 ec 00 04 00 00       sub    $0x400,%esp
+   9:  8b 8c 24 08 04 00 00    mov    0x408(%esp),%ecx
+  10:  89 e3                   mov    %esp,%ebx
+  12:  8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
   18:  8b 14 81                mov    (%ecx,%eax,4),%edx
   1b:  89 14 83                mov    %edx,(%ebx,%eax,4)
   1e:  83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
@@ -28,5 +26,4 @@
   3e:  75 f0                   jne    30 <func+0x30>
   40:  81 c4 00 04 00 00       add    $0x400,%esp
   46:  5b                      pop    %ebx
-  47:  5d                      pop    %ebp
-  48:  c3                      ret    
+  47:  c3                      ret
```

You see multiple kinds of changes:

1. Code with framepointers will always contain the *both* of the two instructions `push %ebp` *and* `mov %esp, %ebp`.
   Framepointer-less code *may* (does not in the shown case, as it's not using the `%ebp` register for anything) have the `push %ebp` but *will not* have the `mov %esp, %ebp` one, as it's not necessary to initialize the framepointer.
2. Code with framepointers accesses arguments on the stack relative to the *framepointer*, like `mov 0x8(%ebp), %ecx` in the shown case.
   Framepointer-less code does so relative to the *stackpointer*, with an additional offset the size of the function's stackframe, like `mov 0x408(%esp), %ecx`.
   The same might be true for local variables, in the shown code that's `lea -0x404(%ebp), %ebx` for the framepointer-using code vs. `mov %esp, %ebx` (could've been `lea 0x0(%esp), %ebx`) for the code without framepointers.
3. There are likely some changes in register allocation between the two, especially if the code becomes complex enough to *use* the `%ebp` register for a local variable (the shown sample isn't showing that)

Compiler optimization levels have quite some impact on how the generated code actually looks like but these specific items mentioned (`mov %esp, %ebp` and the use of `%ebp`-relative addressing for arguments / local variables) are *only* ever found in code that uses framepointers, and missing if you compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

Comment: Note that some functions will still use `%ebp` as a frame pointer, even in compiler output from `-fomit-frame-pointer`.  This happens with C99 variable-length arrays on the stack.  I think the main reason is that stack-unwind data for exception-handling / debugging can't handle variable-sized stack frames.  Also seen with local arrays/objects aligned to more than 16B, because gcc / clang implement that with `and $-32, %rsp` for example.

Comment: For those working with `x86_64`, the registers to look for are the 64-bit equivalents: `%rbp` and `%rsp` - the concept is the same though!

Comment: Any simple tool to tell whether it‘s with frame pointer or not, instead of diving into the detail of assembly?

Comment: @hunter_tech I'm not aware of a "simpler" tool than looking into the generated code. After all, it's interoperable (framepointer-using and framepointer-less code can call each other, there's no limitations on e.g. an optimized library being called by unoptimized code). At least `gcc` and `clang` (two common compilers on UN*X platforms) don't annotate the created object file as "[not] using framepointers".

Comment: `objdump -d $binary | grep -c "mov.*%esp,.*%ebp"`

Comment: @kgibm that's too simple. False positive example: `mov %esp, 20(%ebp, %eax)` will match your regex - yet absolutely not be an indication of framepointer usage. I would agree that "if that count is high" (say, one-permille of all instructions, on-order-of) it's rather likely. A single hit on that regex there isn't necessarily conclusive.

Comment: You can only have heuristics because "frame pointer" is literally just about using `ebp` (32 bit binary) / `rbp` (64 bit binary) to keep/store in stack current/previous stack position during function calls. You can improve performance (optimize the code) by using those registers for actual computations so using "frame pointer" should be considered debugging aid, not a feature of the actual program. The whole question is basically "Can I tell which optimization flags were enabled for a binary during compilation?" and the answer is that you can have heuristics but not ground truth.

Comment: In theory, the compiler could use frame pointer where it doesn't hurt too much but omit frame pointer only if it improves performance so much that losing easier debug support is an acceptable tradeoff. For such a compiler, you cannot even say that frame pointers are enabled or disabled overall because different parts use different logic in the same compilation unit.

Comment: Also note that if the developer of the software added compiler flag `-fasynchronous-unwind-tables` you can have full stacktraces without the frame pointer, too.